# Skip "root" directory when extracting using ZipArchive class?

Tags: php, unzip, php-ziparchive

I am attempting to use the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) class to unzip the contents of a zip containing a GitHub repository.

When you download a zip from GitHub, the zip contains a folder at the root of the zip named something like "project-2302392-20230"... Then within that folder are the actual contents of the repository.

Is it possible extract everything within that project folder without extracting the folder itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to figure out the name of the unique top directory of the github zip archive.

1. use getArchiveComment() to get the ziparchive comment.
2. use strpos to strip away all characters except the first 7 and also add the git username and repo name like so '/USER-REPO-'.substr($comment, 0, 7);

You could also use regex, scandir, and a number of other ways.